# CCSprite is moved when using CCScaleTo or CCScaleBy

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, anchor, box2d, scale, ccsprite

I almost have read everything about Anchor Point and scaling. I still have no idea what is going on with a sprites position when i scale it.

The scenario is this:

When i tap on screen, sprite's width will decrease about %50 and height will increase about same scale. Then it will get back to its normal scale.

```
id scaleUpAction =  [CCEaseInOut actionWithAction:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:.35 scaleX:0.5 scaleY:1.5] rate:1.0];
id scaleDownAction = [CCEaseInOut actionWithAction:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:.35 scaleX:1.0 scaleY:1.0] rate:1.0];
CCSequence *scaleSeq = [CCSequence actions:scaleUpAction, scaleDownAction, nil];
[self.boxShape runAction:scaleSeq];
```

I dont understand why scaling makes the sprites "move".

If I have a sprite with size 40x60 at position (100, 100) on the screen, when I scale it down , it moves left. Why?

Thanks.

Comment: `scaleX:0.5 scaleY:1.5`: that's not 50% in each direction. That's 50% less in X direction, but only 33% up in Y. You probably want `scaleY:2.0`

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when scaling space there is always exactly one point that remains on it's place, other points move. For CCNode this point is the anchor point. So select the point on your node you want to stay in place and make it anchor point

Comment: I've already set anchor point to (0.5f, 0.5f) which means center of ccnode. (I think default of anchor point is also the same).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the anchor point of the image is not located at the mass center of the figure. In the next picture you should set the anchor point in red dot, ccp (0.85, 0.5) approx.!

[Image: Anchor Point, Moon, center of mass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UO3SJ.png)

If your anchor point is located in the center (0.5, 0.5), when the previous figure is scaled horizontally then it will move to the left (Only visually!).

Is this your problem?

Comment: I've solved my problem. In my case when sprite's coordinate changed, background is moved based on sprites new coordinate. Each time sprite is animated (scaled) its bodies position is also changed. I thought it is moved left when scaled.. But the truth is background is moved right. Shame on me :)