# CCScaleTo causes CCSprite to move, apart from scaling it

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, scaling, ccsprite

I am pretty new to Cocos2d and I am trying to implement scaling a sprite up and down.
I am using `CCEaseInOut` to perform the task.
My code snippet looks as follows:

```
barrel setAnchorPoint:ccp(0.5,0.5)];
id scaleUpAction =  [CCEaseInOut actionWithAction:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:.35 scaleX:1.5 scaleY:1.5] rate:1.0];
id scaleDownAction = [CCEaseInOut actionWithAction:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:.35 scaleX:1.0 scaleY:1.0] rate:1.0];
CCSequence *scaleSeq = [CCSequence actions:scaleUpAction, scaleDownAction, nil];
[barrel runAction:scaleSeq];
```

`barrel` is of type `CCNode`.

I have tried to set the `anchorPoint` to `(0.5,0.5)` considering the scaling might be happening around the centre. But, that doesn't seem to help.

I have seen a similar question: [CCSprite is moved when using CCScaleTo or CCScaleBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410367/ccsprite-is-moved-when-using-ccscaleto-or-ccscaleby?rq=1). Unfortunately, there is no answer in that link that solves the problem.

It would be great if someone could point me in the right direction.

**Note:** It might be useful to mention that the barrel object is being used as a `box2d` object. Could the problem be arising from there?
Cheers!

**Note:** I have following already in my code:

`NSObject* bodyUserDataA = (__bridge NSObject*)contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody()->GetUserData();
if ([bodyUserDataA isKindOfClass:[ODPPBarrel class]]) {
        barrel = (ODPPBarrel *)bodyUserDataA;
    }`

Comment: Removing the `barrel setAnchorPoint:ccp(0.5,0.5)];` statement, doesn't solve the problem either.

Answer (score 0):

Always try NOT to change the anchorpoints of a node unless it is a must requirement. By default the anchorpoint for all nodes are set to 0.5 only.

```
id scaleUpAction =  [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:.35 scale:1.5];
id scaleDownAction = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:.35 scale:1.0];
CCSequence *scaleSeq = [CCSequence actions:scaleUpAction, scaleDownAction, nil];
```

Now if barrel is of type CCSprite and used in b2Body's userdata field then: 
get the body (e.g. myBody) from the box2d world.

```
CCSPrite *tmpSPrite = (CCSPrite *)myBody->getUserData;
if(tmpSprite)
  [tmpSPrite runAction:scaleSeq];
```

Comment: Thank you for responding Krish. I am not looking for a popping effect exactly. What I am looking for is quick scaling up of the sprite from 1.0 to 1.5 and then quick scaling down from 1.5 to 1.0. The code you provided seems to be scaling up the sprite from 0.85 to 1.0. However, that's not the issue. The problem that I am facing is, the sprite move  sideways rather than popping out and back in on the same spot. Could you please suggest me what might be wrong with my code? The problem doesn't get solved with the above code either.

Comment: It might be useful to mention that the barrel object is being used as a box2d object. Could the problem be arising from there?

Comment: what is type of barrel? is it of class CCSPrite or is it b2Body or is it CCSprite and used in b2Body's userdata?

Comment: Hi Krish, please see my edited question. I extract the CCSprite from the body in the same way that you have mentioned above. Any pointers as to what might be causing the weird problem?

Comment: I just tested your code in my project. Applied the action to a sprite of a b2Body. to see the action i just set actionwithduratio:1.35. i did all these changes inside update() tick method. All is working fine as expected. No problem with the code what i suggested you. the barrel for me is a of CCSprite type, not ccnode.